# Admin approval and email verification with all-auth

Tags: python, django

I want to implement an admin approval and email confirmation system for the signup process. 
For now, I am using the 'is_active' field set False by default, until the admin sets it manually to True.
It works so far, the only problem is that the confirmation mail is not being sent out when 'is_active' is False.

The email-confirmation flag is actually in another table called accounts_emailaddress, so I am wondering why this is not working?

Depending on which flag is set to False, the user should be redirected to the corresponding Templates.
The user should not be able to log in, unless the email is verified and his profile approved by the administrator.

How can I achieve this result?